# Is the statement Ø ⊆ C true for set C = {7,8}?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm unsure as to if the statement is true or not. I understand that Ø ⊂ C would be true, but I think the answer to this is false because of the distinction between subset and proper subset. If it is true, could someone provide some explanation as to why?

Comment: $\emptyset\subseteq A$ is true for all sets $A$.

Comment: See definition of [Subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset).

Comment: Here's a similar situation. $0 < 2$ is true, just like $\emptyset\subset C$. Thefore, $0\leq 2$ is as true as $\emptyset\subseteq C$. Does that help resolve your confusion?

Comment: Basically, we have to read $A \subseteq B$ as "either $A \subset B$ or $A = B$".

Comment: Or, we can read $A\subset B$ as "$A\subseteq B$ and $A\neq B$". It's completely the same as the difference betwwen $<$ and $\leq$.

Comment: "but I think the answer to this is false because of the distinction between subset and proper subset."  How could something be a proper subset but not a general subset.  If $A \subsetneq C$ is true than it has be that $A \subseteq C$ is true.  Because $A \subseteq C$ means either $A \subsetneq C$ or $A = C$.  ANd that is true.

Comment: "It's completely the same as the difference betwwen < and ≤"  It's universally agreed upon that $<$ means $\lneq$ means "less than and not equal to" and $\le$ means "less than or equal to".  But is is not universally agreed as to whether $\subset$ means $\subsetneq$ means "subset not equal" or whether $\subset$ means $\subseteq$ means "subset maybe equal maybe not."

Comment: @fleablood, you are right, I forgot that there are different conventions there. Which is dumb, since for this particular reason I never use $\subset$ but only $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$. But I'd say if you see both $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ in the same place, it's safe to assume that they do not mean the same, but what I wrote earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in saying that $$ \emptyset \subset \{7,8\}$$

because every element of $\emptyset $ is an element of $\{7,8\}$ but$\{7,8\}$  has two elements which are not element of $\emptyset $

On the other hand $$ \emptyset  \subseteq \{7,8\}$$ because every element of $\emptyset $ is also an element of $\{7,8\}$

Of course we understand that $\emptyset $ does not have any element so it is a subset of every set.

Note that  $\emptyset  $ is not a proper subset of itself, but it is a subset of itself.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `\phi` instead of `\emptyset`?

Comment: @Ennar I really did not know that we have a different notation for the empty set. Do you like me to edit my answer or it is understood what I had in mind?

Comment: It is understandable the way it is, so feel free to leave it or change it, whichever you like better.

Comment: @Ennar Thanks for the comment . I learned something new and edited my answer.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad it was of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

The empty set is a subset of any set $A$. Here is why: assume this is false. That means not every element of $\emptyset$ is an element of $A$. Hence there is an element $x\in\emptyset$ such that $x\notin A$. But this can't happen because $\emptyset$ has no elements at all. A contradiction.

Comment: Does adding brackets to the Ø change the answer? i.e. {Ø} ⊆ A

Comment: Yes, it changes the answer. $\{\emptyset\}$ is not the empty set anymore, this is a set which contains the empty set. (a set of sets). So obviously it is not a subset of every set $A$. In order for $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq A$ to be true we must have $\emptyset\in A$.

Answer (score 0):

$\require {cancel}$

> Is $\cancel{\color{gray}{\emptyset}}\color{green}{\text{Shaquille O'Neal}}\cancel{\color{gray}{\subset C}}\color{green}{\text{is a ball player}}$ true? I'm unsure as to if the statement is true or not. I understand that $\cancel{\color{gray}{\emptyset}}$ $\color{green}{\text{Shaquille O'Neal}}$ $\cancel{\color{gray}{\subset C}}$ $\color{green}{\text{is a basketball player}}$  would be true, but I think the answer to this is false because of the distinction between $\cancel{\color{gray}{\text{subset}}}\color{green}{\text{ball player}}$ and $\cancel{\color{gray}{\text{proper subset}}}\color{green}{\text{basketball player}}$. If it is true, could someone provide some explanation as to why?

It is true. $\cancel{\color{gray}{\text{proper subset}}}\color{green}{\text{basketball player}}$ is a specific type of $\cancel{\color{gray}{\text{subset}}}\color{green}{\text{ball player}}$ that is specifically $\cancel{\color{gray}{\text{not equal}}}\color{green}{\text{plays basketball}}$, whereas $\cancel{\color{gray}{\text{subset}}}\color{green}{\text{ball player}}$ is one that may, or may not, $\cancel{\color{gray}{\text{be unequal}}}\color{green}{\text{play basketball}}$.

.....addendum....

Actually, the term "proper" means not equal *and* not empty.

$\subset$ and $\subsetneq$  do not actually mean "proper".  It just means "not equal".

$\emptyset \subsetneq \{7,8\}$ but $\emptyset$ is not a "proper" subset because it is empty.

=======

Answer 2:

$A \subseteq B$ means either a) $A \subsetneq B$ *OR*  b) $A = B$.

So if $A\subsetneq B$ is true then a) is true.  So  a) or b) is true.

So if $A\subsetneq B$ is true then $A\subseteq B$ is also true.

And if $A = B$ is true then $A \subseteq B$ is also true.

Basically there are 5 possibilities:

1) $A=\emptyset; B= \emptyset$ then: $A \subsetneq B$ is false.  $A = B$ is true.  $A \subseteq B$ is true.  "A is a subset of B" is true.  "A is a proper subset of B" is false.  "A is an unequal subset of B" is false.

2) $A = \emptyset; B \ne \emptyset$ then:  $A \subsetneq B$ is true.  $A = B$ is false.  $A \subseteq B$ is true.  "A is a subset of B" is true.  "A is a proper subset of B" is false (proper subsets can't be empty).  "A is an unequal subset of B" is true.

3) $A$ is not empty and $A$ has an element that is not in $B$ then:  $A \subsetneq B$ is false.  $A = B$ is false.  $A \subseteq B$ is false.  "A is a subset of B" is false.  "A is a proper subset of B" is false.  "A is an unequal subset of B" is false.

4) $A$ is not empty; Every element in $A$ is in $B$ but $B$ has elements that $A$ does not have then:  $A \subsetneq B$ is true.  $A = B$ is false.  $A \subseteq B$ is true.  "A is a subset of B" is true.  "A is a proper subset of B" is true.  "A is an unequal subset of B" is true.

5) $A$ is not emepty and $A$ and $B$ have precisely the same elements then:   $A \subsetneq B$ is false.  $A = B$ is true.  $A \subseteq B$ is true.  "A is a subset of B" is true.  "A is a proper subset of B" is false.  "A is an unequal subset of B" is false.

Those are really the only 5 options.

BTW.  It is not universally agreed upon what $A \subset B$ means.  So texts will tell you it means $A \subsetneq B$ but other texts will tell you it means $A \subseteq B$.  I, personally, prefer it to mean $A\subseteq B$ but it is clear you meant it to mean $A \subsetneq B$.